# Adding intellisense to custom html tags

Tags: html, visual-studio, tags

Where is the intellisense information stored for html tags? I'm creating custom tags and not sure how to create intellisense for the different attributes I would expect this custom tag to have. Since these tags I'm creating are not recognized as legit html tags when in fact I can still perform actions on them via JQuery, this is causing me some confusion as to how to get intellisense for attributes I create to show up.

Comment: Are you talking about Visual Studio? What version?

Comment: VS 2013. I have custom tag called "optionslist" and have a few attributes Im using. Not sure how to get those to show up in intellisence.